# converting hash to XML using xmlsimple in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-serialization

I have a hash of the following format

```
{
 '1234' => {"key1"=>1234,"key2"=>"sdfsdf","key3"=>"sdfsdfs"},
 '234' => {"key1"=>234,"key2"=>"sdfsdf","key3"=>"sdfsdfs"}
}
```

I want to convert it to xml like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyKeys>
  <MyKey>
    <Key1>1234/Key1>
    <Key2>sdfsdf</Key2>
    <Key3>sdfsdfs</Key3>
  </MyKey>
  <MyKey>
    <Key1>234/Key1>
    <Key2>sdfsdf</Key2>
    <Key3>sdfsdfs</Key3>
  </MyKey>
</MyKeys>
```

the issue is, xmlsimple is not doing that. instead of putting , it is creating <1234> tag.

I want to get rid of this.... any help? even ActiveSupport to_xml does the same. any other options available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for the outer hash is definitely `1234` and `234`. xmlsimple is doing the correct parsing. You havent mentioned of `MyKeys` or `MyKey` in your hash. You should convert the hash to your required format before converting it to xml.

```
hash = {
 '1234' => {"key1"=>1234,"key2"=>"sdfsdf","key3"=>"sdfsdfs"},
 '234' => {"key1"=>234,"key2"=>"sdfsdf","key3"=>"sdfsdfs"}
}
converted_hash = Hash[hash.map{|k, v| ["MyKey", v]}]
result_hash = {"MyKeys" => converted_hash}
```

Use xmlsimple on this hash.

Comment: i wanted to use the hash for searching also. hence i cannot convert the keys to mykey. more over i dont want parse through the hash and change the keys.

Comment: what i actually did was, I passed the hash.values which is nothing but the array of hashes. then to_xml was able to generated the way i needed.