# How do I parse a hash to XML using XmlSimple?

Tags: ruby, hash, xml-parsing, xml-simple

I have a hash that i wanted to parse to XML using SimpleXML but there is a trick I dont know how to handle:

My hash looks like:

```
require 'xmlsimple'
test = { "subroot" => {
  field1 => {'var1' = ['xyz'], 'var2' = ['yyyy']},
  field2 => {'var1' = ['xyz'], 'var2' = ['yyyy']},
  field3 => {'var1' = ['xyz'], 'var2' = ['yyyy']}, 
  'id' = 'xxxxxx'} }
```

I parse it to XML using:

```
XmlSimple.xml_out(teste, 'RootName' => 'root')
```

resulting in:

```
<cenario>
  <subroot id="xxxxxx">
     <field1>
       <var1>xyz</var1>
       <var2>yyyy</var2>
     </field1>
     <field2>
       <var1>xyz</var1>
       <var2>yyyy</var2>
     </field2>
     <field3>
       <var1>xyz</var1>
       <var2>yyyy</var2>
     </field3>
   </subroot>
</cenario>
```

That's OK and works like a charm but there is problem when I need to loop. 
Im doing a automated test that loops on each test and save the test data on a Hash and by the end of the tests i need to save it on a xml and i need to get something like this:

```
<cenario>
      <subroot id="xxxxxx">
         <field1>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field1>
         <field2>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field2>
         <field3>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field3>
       </subroot>
      .
      .
      .
      <subroot id="xxxx10x">
         <field1>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field1>
         <field2>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field2>
         <field3>
           <var1>xyz</var1>
           <var2>yyyy</var2>
         </field3>
       </subroot>
    </cenario>
```

merging each hash on each test will not do the trick cz it prevents the last hash (subroot)
Did i made myself clear?
Can't simpleXML do the trick or do I need to look for another solution?

Comment: please rephrase your question, it's hard to say what you want.

Comment: There's a problem when you need to loop? Can you be a bit more specific about that?

Comment: Sorry, bad english. Im doing a automated test script thats need to save each test data for further check. 
For accomplish that, my app save each test loop( Junit... @test... @parametrization..got it?) on a hash and by the end of the tests, i need to save it as a XML.
Problem is that that i cant repeat the "subroot" name on the hash (duhh) but my xml gotta have same pattern. <root><subroot id=(Test)>....fields... </subroot><subroot id=(Test)>.....fields....</subroot></root>

Sorry, but its kind of hard to write it down clearly.

Comment: tried to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193587/converting-hash-to-xml-using-xmlsimple-in-ruby solution but it didnt worked out... changed subroot text for a String with test id... hash populated right but when i convert it.. it deletes all the entries except the last one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thks for the help...

I figured out that i dont need Hash keys if i put a "instance" of the hash inside a array...
I can use the same Hash name, each array slot saves a instance of my hash than i can call simpleXML or to_xml

No i just need to figure out how to remove the objects tags that makes the xml bigger.